# Google Map Polyline path

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

How can make the path with traffic area red color and light traffic with yellow color, how can handle it?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imh6h.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is in the [Input Method Framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/im/InputContext.html).

```
InputContext ic = InputContext.getInstance();
Locale locale = ic.getLocale();
```

Now one has the current locale like en_US.

```
System.out.println(locale.getLanguage()); // ar/en
```

One may switch the keyboard locale with:

```
if (!ic.selectInputMethod(locale)) {
    // Failed to switch...
}
```

Comment: I tried all methods but the results are always wrong Is there an effective way possible I use

Comment: I typed the wrong class name, should have been InputContext, but in a small swing app it detected the keyboard layout switch to another language. Under Windows as icon in the bar below: EN or AR.

Comment: this function return true not EN or AR

Comment: I have clarified the answer, `getLocale()` returns the locale.